# Gemius AMP Tag implementation GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

Is there a way to use an  gemius-tag in GTM?
The Gemius Tag is allowed in amp pages as a hardcoded tag , but i can't figure out how to implement it using GTM. There is no template available and there is no way of using custom html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Gemius does not provide a GTM Template and after further investigation do not intend to do so, because they simply do not trust Tag Managers.